Makefile order only pre-req runs multiple times
I am trying to log meta data information like C and cpp flags to a files cflags.txt & cxxflags.txt and i want to generate this files only once when first .c file is getting compiled. There are 100's of source files which will get compile as part of my project where i don't want to run the rule that creates cflags.txt & cxxflags.txt for each c/cpp compilation. I have created order-only pre-req to run it only once. But somreason i can see the message inside metadata multiple times in build log which means rule is running multiple times right ? Am i missing something here?
CFLAGS_FILE := $(METADATA_DIR)/cflags.txt
CXXFLAGS_FILE := $(METADATA_DIR)/cxxflags.txt

METADATA_DIR :=  $(BUILD_DIR)

TEST_LOGGED  := $(METADATA_DIR)/.metadata_logged

$(OBJSUBDIR)%$(OBJSUFFIX) : %.c | $(TEST_LOGGED)
   $(CC) $(__CFLAGS__) -o $@ -c $< 

$(OBJSUBDIR)%$(OBJSUFFIX) : %.cpp | $(TEST_LOGGED)
   $(CXX) $(__CXXFLAGS__) -o $@ -c $< 


$(TEST_LOGGED): | $(METADATA_DIR)
    $(ECHO) "$(__CFLAGS__)" > $(CFLAGS_FILE)
    $(ECHO) "$(__CXXFLAGS__)" > $(CXXFLAGS_FILE)
    $(TOUCH) $(TEST_LOGGED)

$(METADATA_DIR):
    $(MKDIR) $@


Make will only ever try to build a given target one time, regardless of what kind of prerequisite is used or how often it appears.  There is no way to get make to rebuild the same target multiple times within a single invocation of make.  If you are seeing that line printed multiple times AND your makefile is as described above and the values of these variables are as described above, then all I can suggest is you're using a recursive invocation of make and each invocation is trying to rebuild that target for some reason.  You've hidden a lot of potentially useful info behind variables here.

If you can't figure it out the easy thing to do is run make -d and then examine the output (there will be a lot of it...) looking for where and why make decides to rebuild the .metadata_logged target.

No run of make will build a given target more than once.  You have not presented enough information for us to determine why you see the "inside metadata" message more than once, but I note that (i) for clarity, you should use a shell command such as echo to produce output from recipes, not $(info). And (ii) the recipe might run multiple times if make runs multiple times.  If there are sub-makes involved, for example.

Note, the $(info ...) (assuming it is really as it appears: indented with a TAB) is only expanded when the recipe of the target is expanded / the target is out of date.  Not every time the makefile is parsed.

Thanks, @MadScientist, I had time to edit my comment.  It's more opinionated now, but less incorrect.

yes, i do see some recursion happening as part of build flow. Cant we avoid running rule multiple times in recursion mode?

Well, every instance of make will do its own evaluation of the target to see if it's up to date.  Every instance of make that determines the target is out of date, will rebuild it.  There's no way to have the different instances of make communicate with each other to say "I'm building this so you don't have to".  However, once one instance of make builds the target then the other instances should see it as up to date and not build it again.  So, either you are running multiple instances in parallel so they all see the target as out of date and try to build it at the same time, or...

There's something more to your makefile than you show here.  In this makefile, the ONLY reason .metadata_logged would be rebuilt is if it doesn't exist.  But you  must have more to your real makefile, since otherwise these .txt files would never be updated when you changed these variables.  Maybe in your real makefile you list other prerequisites of this target.  Without an accurate example of what you have we can't provide an accurate answer.

"Cant we avoid running rule multiple times in recursion mode?" -- yes, by ensuring that only one of the make runs involved builds any targets that depend (in order-only fashion, directly or indirectly) on .metadata_logged.  Depending on the details, that could be either easy and natural or very difficult indeed.  Of course, you could also consider switching to non-recursive style. See Recursive Make Considered Harmful for a discussion of some of the pitfalls of recursive make, such as the one that seems to have caught you.

@MadScientist, I understood the problem is that rules are running in different directory hence .metadata_logged file is trying to search for current working directory where it does not exists and make is trying to create that file. Another problem that comes is while running build in parallel mode on windows env, It fails with echo: write error: Bad file descriptor ,In serial mode -j1 build works fine and metadata is also logged to files cflags.txt cxxflags.txt successfully. Looks like race condition is happening where  rule is trying to run at the same time hits into issue.

@MadScientist, Any other approach that helps to workaround ?

Updated the question with more details.

There is only one solution: you have to write your makefiles to ensure that only one instance of make is trying to update this target file.  However you do that is fine but there's no other possible way to make it work.  There's nothing in the makefile example you provide that speaks to how multiple instances of make are started; that must happen through some other makefile somewhere that is invoking this makefile that builds this target multiple times in parallel.  You have to prevent that.  For example, the "parent" makefile can create these files before running sub-makes.

In short, if you have multiple instances of make running at the same time trying to build the same target file(s), it can never work reliably.

I have verified that there is only one instance of make invocation happening. Issue is because of target trying to write to same file at the same time which happens during parallel runs. In serial runs there is no issue.

No Luck in adding .NOTPARALLE: $(TEST_LOGGED) :(
